# What is the default environment font in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

The settings path is `Tools / Options / Environment / Fonts and Colors /`**`Enrivonment`**`/ Font`. I'm talking about the Environment that I emphasized in bold in the settings path.

[image: Tools / Options / Environment / Fonts and Colors / Enrivonment / Font]

Notice how it doesn't tell you what the default font is; it just says `Automatic`. And the font size is disabled until you pick a specific font.

If I want to change the font size, it makes me pick the font first. But I have no reason to change the font, just the font size. Soo, what's the default Environment font?

It's probably the same as in Visual Studio 2015, which also hides it.

Comment: It is just a system font that other programs use as well.  You'd use the Display applet in Control Panel to select it, albeit that every Windows version does it differently.  We don't know your Windows version, ask at superuser.com with the title "how to change the default tooltip font and size".

Comment: @HansPassant, I appreciate the information, but I'm not trying to change my font settings for all of windows; just Visual Studio.

Comment: Amazing, exactly the question I typed into Google.

Comment: 9pt is a hilariously awful default 

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It turned out to be `Leelawadee UI` for Windows 10 Professional.

For other OS versions, you can put the focus on the font dropdown, and up and down arrow, or press the first letter of the font, or press <kbd>Home</kbd> to go back to Automatic (the first dropdown option). Thereby, you can keep your eye on the Sample window to determine the default font. If you get on a font, then hit the <kbd>Home</kbd> key, and the Sample doesn't change (even a little bit), that's your default font. Please leave a comment if you find one!

[image]

Comment: 12pt is right. 9 is just too small for my ole eyes.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT, yeah, me too. I don't know how these kids do it lol

Comment: For Windows 7, I think it is "Microsoft New Tai Lue"

Comment: This also applies to SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), at least for Windows 10 and SSMS 17.2 -- Leelawadee UI. So if you want to change the Object Explorer font size, choose Leelawadee UI. You can verify this by selecting Leelawadee UI and then clicking Use Defaults and see that the Sample does not change.

Comment: What a difference 12 pt makes. Nice!

Comment: Is there not a way to programatically retrieve this value?